# Save cropped image from bbox

Tags: python, opencv, crop

I am using cvlib for detecting object and I want to be able to save the cropped imaged based on the bbox coordinates.

I have this in my code:

```
 def detect_object(img):
       
    # Open image
    image_stream = io.BytesIO(img)
    image_stream.seek(0)
    file_bytes = np.asarray(bytearray(image_stream.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(file_bytes, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Detection
    bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(frame)
    output_image = draw_bbox(frame, bbox, label, conf)

    return output_image, bbox, label, conf
```

and when I print bbox y get:

```
[3, -23, 1231, 731]
```

So, I want to use these coordinates to crop the original image and save only de detected object defined by these coordinates

Something like this:

```
crop = output_image[bbox[2]:bbox[1], bbox[0]:bbox[3],:]
cv2.imwrite("crop.png", crop)
```

But when I do this I realised that the crop doesn't contain the desired object, the coordinates are wrong.

How can I fix it? Why am I getting negative coordinates?

My Image is 1280x720 and the desired object occupies approximately the entire image.

Comment: you need to handle negative indices. numpy interprets them as offsets from the end of the dimension. you probably want to clip them to 0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using as reference the comment from @Christoph Rackwitz, i.e handling the offsets:

```
image_height, image_width, image_channels = output_image.shape
box_xmin, box_ymin, box_xmax, box_ymax = bbox

if box_xmin < 0:
    box_xmin = 0
                    
if box_ymin < 0:
    box_ymin = 0

if box_xmax > image_width:
    box_xmax = image_width

if box_ymax > image_height:
    box_ymax = image_height

                    
crop = output_image[box_ymin:box_ymax, box_xmin:box_xmax,:]
cv2.imwrite("crop.jpg", crop)
```